# Deserialize array of objects with int property to array of ints using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following JSON...

```
{
  "name":"MyThings",
  "things":[
    {
      "num":"123"
    },
    {
      "num":"456"
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I have this much of the mapping...

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ThingList {
    private String name;
    private int[] nums;
}
```

How do I essentially do a map from object array to int array using Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom deserializer for this:

```
class DeSerializer extends StdDeserializer<ThingList> {

  protected DeSerializer() {
    super(ThingList.class);
  }

  @Override
  public ThingList deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
    // use p.getText() and p.nextToken to navigate through the xml and construct ThingList object
    return something;
  }
```

Initialize the parser as follows with the deserializer:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("configModule", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addDeserializer(ThingList.class, new DeSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
ThingList tl = mapper.readValue(<json string>, ThingList.class);
```

Comment: How does this work when integrating with something like Spring's RestTemplate?

Comment: Annotate the ThingList class with `@JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)`